# Return a concatenated string from recursive function (getting all the values of a nested dict / list json) - Python 3.9.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, recursion

I'm trying to get all the values of an specific key (that appear multiple times) into a json nested object of dicts and lists in Python 3.9.7

I can get the value already, but the part of returned it...

Here is my code:

Where:

- current collection: is the, as it name says, the current collection to be evaluated
- inner_key: the name of the key to get its value (i.e. "inner_key": value_to_get)
- saving_value: an empty string (in the first function call) to save all the values of the incidences of inner_key

```py
def get_inner_value_nested_collections(current_collection, inner_key, saving_value):    
    if isinstance(current_collection, dict):
        for current_value in current_collection:
            if current_value == inner_key:
                saving_value += str(current_collection[current_value]) + "\n"
                # if I print current_collection[current_value], the value is one of the values I want, but saving_value is not concatenating nothing
            else:
                if isinstance(current_collection[current_value], dict) or isinstance(current_collection[current_value], list):
                    get_inner_value_nested_collections(current_collection[current_value], inner_key, saving_value)
    elif isinstance(current_collection, list):
        for current_value in current_collection:
            if isinstance(current_value, dict) or isinstance(current_value, list):
                get_inner_value_nested_collections(current_value, inner_key, saving_value)
```

I tried adding the returns and am still not getting the correct value:

```py
def get_inner_value_nested_collections(current_collection, inner_key, saving_value):    
    if isinstance(current_collection, dict):
        for current_value in current_collection:
            if current_value == inner_key:
                saving_value += str(current_collection[current_value]) + "\n"
                return saving_value
                # if I print current_collection[current_value], the value is one of the values I want, but saving_value is not concatenating nothing
            else:
                if isinstance(current_collection[current_value], dict) or isinstance(current_collection[current_value], list):
                    return get_inner_value_nested_collections(current_collection[current_value], inner_key, saving_value)
    elif isinstance(current_collection, list):
        for current_value in current_collection:
            if isinstance(current_value, dict) or isinstance(current_value, list):
                return get_inner_value_nested_collections(current_value, inner_key, saving_value)
```

I think that is because I have no base case (when all the json has been iterated) to really return... but no idea how to express this into code.

Comment: No, no, I know how to return, the thing is that I want to return all the things inside of saving_value, but I don't know in which exact line returned it and not get a None or empty string, since is a recursive function is hard for me to tell where to place the returns

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Python.  When you wrote `saving_value += str(....)` you are creating a new `saving_value` that gets stored in the local variable.  This value never gets returned.

Instead make `saving_value` a list, and append your results onto it.  You will find it at the end that it contains all your results.

Comment: I tried it, you were right, but it didn't worked... still not having any value in the list, I'm really confused for being honest, I thought that since it was a list, no matter the iterations, it will kept the data in it... and nothing

Comment: You're going to need to show your code.  Did you do something like `result = []` followed by calling your function with `result` as the third argument?

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm talking about your first piece of code.  Did you change `+=` to `.append()`?